# Quadtree equivalent of AVL tree

Tags: data-structures, graphics, binary-search-tree, computer-science, quadtree

I am looking for a quadtree/octree/2^n tree that self-balances as it accepts new observations, without knowledge of every other point, iow, it cannot rely on the median as I am writing in a 'streaming' context.  The AVL tree balances as it goes by pivoting, is there another similar data structure for higher dimensioned data?

Comment: Why do you need a quadtree?

Comment: Because I am searching for points in a plane.  Quadtrees partition the plane into box regions which seems like a good way to get logarithmic time search.

Comment: See http://www.win.tue.nl/~kbuchin/teaching/2IL55/slides/07quadtrees.pdf.

Comment: Why do you need balancing? If  the data is more dense in one (e.g geographical) region, then the depth is logically higher. This is good, this is the adaption. Otherwise you would have too many hits as a final result. The goal of the quadtree is to result only a few objects near the queried location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVL tree, returns only one result, the element to find.
But especiall the ebucket based quadtrees return a list of objects near the queried location. The calling programm finally has to inspect all objects in the result for that ones that fullfill the application task.

From that perspective balancing makes little sense. A more dense region (e.g city) has more detailed structures and therefore has a deeper quadtree.
This is not bad. I don't see any need for quad balancing.

Further for all quadtree types (point, lines, object quadtrees) a quad node when it is splitted, it always splitts in 4 equal size sub rectangular or quadratic sub nodes. These types are called restricted quad trees. There is only one hint in literature I have found on balanced quadtrees (M.Bern, D-Eppstein and J.Gilbert: Probably good mesh generations, cited in Hanan Samet: Foundations on Multidimensional Spatial Data Strcutures). If you have academic interest you might read the paper, otherwise I doubt it has value to you.

Otherwise it is not a normal (i.e restricted) quad tree. Read more on R-Trees for sub dividinbg the space in individual rectangles. (R-trees are a competitor to quad trees)
The only quad type balancing that corresponds to a quad tree, could be a dynamic bucket size. But for that I don't see an advantage.

About garuantees:
The maximum depth of the final built up static quad tree, gives an upper bound. (Feel free to measure an average depth). The max bucket size, too gives an upper bound. (Again measure the avg bucket size).

Balancing:
The structure of a quad tree depends on the order of the inserted values.
The values to insert into a quad tree are usually static, so the can be ordered in advance. There are specific pre-orderings that give a (slightly) better balance.

Please note that a quad tree is a spatial index wich is not well usefull for deletions.

Comment: I think I'm missing some nuance in your response, or I'm not missing something and I disagree. Feel free to guide my thinking in the right direction: If I can guarantee the depth for any 1 point is between say, n and n+1, then I can make certain guarantees about the algorithmic runtime of a query against the dataset.  With bucketing you'd have to have similar guarantees about the size of the buckets.  Constructing a balanced tree over a map would result in some goofy partitions - i.e.; through the middle of a city, but I don't think it's unreasonable to ask about.

Comment: You must read more about quadtrees, there are many differnet types of them, with totally diffferent task and behavior: Point Quadtrees, Line Quadtrees and Object (Rectangle) Quadtrees, and even more. So first you must state which type of quad tree you are talking about. Second  all quadtrees split in exactly 4 equal size sub nodes. Othwwise it is not a quadtree, Maybe a R-Tree. Rectangle Quadtrees without buckets (bucket size = 1) need to much space. Andf it even is not possible to always have one rectangle on one quad mode (concentric rectangles)

Comment: Which technical detail in the quadftree you want to modify to achieve balancing? differnt sized sub node rectangle bounds?

Comment: The R-tree meets my requirements perfectly, as it is spatial, balanced and has an upper bound on the bucket size and can re-balance after insertion.  My question was probably ill-posed by asking for a "quadtree" specifically.